# If $ \pmb z $ lies on the circle $\pmb |z|=2$ then show that $\frac{|1|}{|z^4-4z^2+3|}\leq\frac13$ .

Tags: complex-numbers

I tried solving the above problem by substituting $\pmb z^2$ as $\pmb x$ . Which gave me the result 
$$\frac{|1|}{|(x-1)(x-3)|}  \leq \frac13$$ . I am unable to solve further than this .Also here $z$ is a complex number .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What's `\pmb` ?

Comment: Check now (post edited ).

Comment: Why do you write $\lvert1\rvert$ instead of simply writing $1$?

Comment: I'm very very sorry for all the inconvenience caused

Answer (score 2):

If I have read the question correctly you want to show that $|\frac 1 {z^{4}-4z^{3}+3}| \leq \frac  1 3$. This is easy. $|z^{4}-4z^{3}+3|=|(z^{2}-3)(z^{2}-1)|$. Since $|z^{2}-3| \geq |z|^{2}-3 =1$ and $|z^{2}-1| \geq |z|^{2}-1 =3$ we get $|(z^{2}-3)(z^{2}-1)| \geq 3$. Hence $|\frac 1 {z^{4}-4z^{3}+3}| \leq \frac  1 3$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer . I'm a bit confused but have you used triangle inequality ? .And I don't understand line 3 and line 4 and how did we get to this step $|(z^{2}-3)(z^{2}-1)| \geq 3$

Comment: $|a-b| \geq |a|-|b|$ for any two complex numbers $a$ and $b$. This comes from the fact that $|a| =|(a-b)+b| \leq |a-b| +|b|$.